# Firebase warning when entering chat message

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am running an `react-native` chat app example from [Even Bacon](https://blog.expo.io/how-to-build-a-chat-app-with-react-native-3ef8604ebb3c). I can enter my name successfully. But when I enter a chat message, then I have a warning about `firebase`, the chat message was not taken:

[image]

Here is the `Chat.js`:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import Fire from '../Fire';

class Chat extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation}) => ({
        title: (navigation.state.params || {}).name || 'Chat!',
    });

    state = {
        messages: [],
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        Fire.shared.on(message =>
              this.setState(previousState => ({
                messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, message),
              }))
        );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      Fire.shared.off();
    }

    get user() {
      // return our name and our UID for GiftedChat to parse
      return {
          name: this.props.navigation.state.params.name,
          _id: Fire.shared.uid,
      };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <GiftedChat 
              messages={this.state.messages}
              onSend={Fire.shared.send}
              user={this.user}
            /> 
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});



export default Chat;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set up your database rules like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Comment: While this may/will remove the error message, any such instructions should always come with a warning that these rules give everyone (who knows the URL of your database) complete read and write access to all data. It should only be used in (very early stages) of the development cycle.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen totally agree to you on that.